# Classic ASP - Running .exe from a Web Page on Localhost

Tags: asp-classic, localhost, server-side, wsh

I am trying to execute a .bat to launch notepad.exe on my localhost(server-side) with the following code:

index.asp

```
<%
set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
return = wshell.run("c:\file.bat", 4, false)
response.write(return)
set wshell = nothing 
%>
```

file.bat

```
notepad.exe
```

When I open the ASP page, nothing happens. A value 0 is returned because of the variable "return". So I tried set the *false* value to be *true*, and then the server froze and didn't return anything; I think that happened because there were no values to be returned from the .bat file.
I tried also running the notepad.exe (*C:\Windows\notepad.exe*) directly instead of using a .bat file but still nothing happened. I also tried using ASPExec.dll but to no avail either.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

More info:

My local web server is IIS7 that comes with Windows 7. I am doing this on localhost just for testing purposes. I have to accomplish this in Classic ASP because eventually I will have to import the website to a WinCE7 device. I am aware that WshShell is not available for WinCE but for now I am just trying to see if it works. Eventually I will need to be able to run a .exe that installs updates on the device through the website.

Comment: @Aaron: I am trying to run an application on the server-side through a web page. I was using IIS on Windows 7 for testing purposes only.

Comment: What I meant was - what task are you trying to accomplish with the application being run server-side?

Comment: @Aaron: I apologize for misunderstanding the question. I want to be able to remotely update and perform maintenance on device through the web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [running an exe in asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584320/running-an-exe-in-asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is running as a non-interactive IIS user; it cannot interact with the local desktop.

Comment: Is there a way to make it interactive? I am not sure if I have to change settings on the IIS or if it is no possible.

Comment: And what sense does this make? Who do you think will be interacting with Notepad?

Comment: @John: As he said in the question, he eventually wants to run this on WinCE.

Comment: @John: I do understand that I would be one interacting it, and would serve no purposes. I am also aware that if the code worked, I couldn't know for sure if the application was running on client-side or server-side because it is same computer.